# How to store excel files properly while using Django

Tags: python, django

I am switching a Python application with a classic GUI on the local machine to a cloud-based application on my Django website and would like to know the proper way to store my users files while processing the application.

Currently I am using the `FileField` class within the `models` module to upload the files. I have the `upload_to=` parameter set to a new folder anmed `spreadsheets/`. I am wondering if this is the correct way to be storing files that will be processed and then discarded shortly after. Or should I be storing the files in memory (somehow) to make the process quicker and the code more simple?

Current models.py:

```
class Spreadsheets(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    xls = models.FileField(upload_to='spreadsheets/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Current views.py function handling the upload:

```
@login_required
def upload_sheet(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ss_form = SpreadsheetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if ss_form.is_valid():
            ss_form.save()
            return redirect('sheet_list')
    else:
        ss_form = SpreadsheetForm
    return render(request, 'uploader/upload_sheet.html', {
        'ss_form': ss_form
    })
```

Also, the `Model` class expects to have `title` given as a parameter. Is there a way to tell Python to disregard this parameter in the `Spreadsheets` sub-class?

Comment: I think the way you're doing it is probably fine. Provided the relevant files are *actually deleted* after they're done being used, there shouldn't be much of a performance hit - doubly so if the spreadsheet processing happens mostly on the client side. But that's more of a surface-level opinion.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My main concern was that I am going to have to write a function to delete these files once the processing is finished which would add to the computing. I know it seems a bit *perfectionist* but I do not want to get into bad habits if possible. Also, the spreadsheet processing is going to happen server-side. Is there a way to make the clients computer process the data with the code being in the cloud?

Comment: You don't have to delete the files right after they are processed. You can create a scheduled clean up task that runs when the server is idle (e.g. at night).

Comment: One package that comes to mind is tempfile. It's not necessarily the right tool for this job, but it's great for situations like generating reports for users to download that you don't want to keep around after. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!